# File path throw exception in FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource()

Tags: java, javafx, path

I try run program and exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at Controllers.UserOptionsController.pokreniSimulacijuAction(UserOptionsController.java:90)
```

Problem is path in getResource():

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(File.separator+"View"+File.separator+"DodajVozilo.fxml"));
```

May I use *File.separator* or I must use "/" when configure path? It work with "/".
I was run program on Windows 10. 
If I use "/" may I compile program on other OS?

Comment: getClass().getResource(..) can return a null. Make sure its not null and then pass to load method

Comment: @vmaroli It work with FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/View/DodajVozilo.fxml"))...

Comment: `Class.getResource` and related methods are a cross-platform API; no matter what OS you're on it expects the separator to be `/`. Also, it's important to realize that while resources are often files (likely packaged in a JAR file), they are conceptually different from files. Do not use the `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file.*` APIs to access resources.